# how can I restore the removed onClick attribute?

Tags: javascript, dom

In the addBlocker function, I removed the onClick attribute from the button.
In the removeBlocker function, I need that attribute back along with the handler function which was implemented in the html file.

(I tried another approach where I used element.style.pointerEvents = 'none')
but with that, I can't get clientX and clientY value from the event. Is there any way to get clientX and clientY when pointEvents is set to none?

```
document.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    if (e.target.type === 'button') {
        newBody[i].removeAttribute('onClick');
    }
    newBody[i].addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    const { clientX, clientY } = e;
    // newBody[i].style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    // const elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(clientX, clientY);
    let elementMouseIsOver = document.querySelectorAll(':hover');
    elementMouseIsOver = elementMouseIsOver[elementMouseIsOver.length - 1];
    console.log({ clientX, clientY, elementMouseIsOver });
});
```

I expect to get back the removed onClick attribute when I run another function or find a way to get e.clientX and e.clientY when style.pointEvents is none.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the event on `mouseleave`

```
document.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
  if (e.target.type === 'button') {
    newBody[i].setAttribute('onClick', functionName);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to restore the attribute value later, you'll have to retrieve it before you remove the attribute and store it somewhere.

Declare a place to store it:

```
var buttonClick;
```

Where you're removing it

```
buttonClick = newBody[i].getAttribute('onClick');
```

Where you're restoring it:

```
newBody[i].setAttribute('onClick', buttonClick);
```

You can even store it on the element itself by using an *expando property* (basically, a property with an obscure name you're fairly sure won't conflict with anyone else's):

```
newBody[i].__my_blocker_buttonClick = newBody[i].getAttribute('onClick');
```

Then where you're restoring it:

```
newBody[i].setAttribute('onClick', newBody[i].__my_blocker__buttonClick);
```